# Hide php extension in folder (dir) on apache server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ftp, server

I am using my apache server simple with mod_dir, something like this [show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVUcu.png). My php file is changePassword.php which redirects to psswdChanger folder.

```
<?php
/* Redirect browser */
header("Location: ./psswdChanger/");

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

I need to **HIDE** .php exptension, so I want in my directory only changePassword file which will redirects to psswdChanger folder (.php extension must be hidden). It can not be only php file, it can be some other types of file, which can do redirect to psswdChanger folder, but with no extension.

Comment: Google "apache url rewriting"

Comment: If you rewrite "psswdChanger/" back to your changePassword.php file, it's just going to redirect again, causing a redirect loop.

Comment: It is not about URL rewriting, I need to hide php extension in DIR on server, I do not want to edit URL address.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention you're running an apache server, the easiest way to do this would be to save a .htaccess file in the directory the php file exists in.

in the htacess file add :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite changePassword.php to /changePassword - however I have to ask, why are you trying to hide the file extension?

Comment: This will fail if you attempt to go to a page that doesn't exist, will cause a 500 server error. Also doesn't account for trailing slash.

Comment: It is fails, I also tried something with .htaccess before I wrote this post. The extension is still there and if I click on changePassword.php it shows the error The requested URL /test4/psswdChanger/.php was not found on this server.